# fastest algorithm for sum queries in a range

Tags: algorithm, sum, range

Assume we have the following data, which consists of a consecutive 0's and 1's (the nature of data is that there are very very very few **1**s.

> data =
>   [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**1**,**1**,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**1**,**1**,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,**1**,**1**,**1**,**1**,0,0]

so a huge number of zeros, and then possibly some ones (which indicate that some sort of an event is happening).

You want to query this data **many times**. The query is that given two indices `i` and `j` what is `sum(data[i:j])`. For example, `sum_query(i=12, j=25) = 2` in above example.

Note that you have all these queries in advance.

**What sort of a data structure can help me evaluate all the queries as fast as possible?**

*My initial thoughts:*

- preprocess the `data` and obtain two shorter arrays: `data_change` and `data_cumsum`. The `data_change` will be filled up with the indices for when the sequence of **1**s will start and when the next sequence of **0**s will start, and so on. The `data_cumsum` will contain the corresponding cummulative sums up to indices represented in `data_change`, i.e. `data_cumsum[k] = sum(data[0:data_change[k]])`
- In above example, the preprocessing results in: `data_change=[8,11,18,20,31,35]` and `data_cumsum=[0,3,3,5,5,9]`
- Then if query comes for `i=12` and `j=25`, I will do a binary search in this sorted `data_change` array to find the corresponding index for `12` and then for `25`, which will result in the 0-based indices: `bin_search(data_change, 12)=2` and `bin_search(data_change, 25)=4`.
- Then I simply output the corresponding difference from the cumsum array: `data_cumsum[4] - data_cumsum[2]`.  (I won't go into the detail of handling the situation where the any endpoint of the query range falls in the middle of the sequence of 1's, but those cases can be handled easily with an if-statement.

Comment: which language?

Comment: I am using Python. But I think I am mainly asking for ideas on Data Structures or Algorithms.

Comment: So... you already have a O(log n)-per-query algorithm? Why is it not sufficient?

Comment: Well, I am looking for the best possible solution. Any ideas that are out there which I don't know about. I am sure people have thought about it already. Especially since there are many queries, would there be a way to make it even more efficient to simultaneously handle them all...

Comment: @user1780424 Do any of the answers already posted suit your need?

Answer (score 3):

With linear space, linear preprocessing, constant query time,  you can store an array of sums. The i'th position gets the sum of the first i elements. To get query(i,j) you take the difference of the sums (sums[j] - sums[i-1]).

Comment: True, by sacrificing on having extra O(n) space, we can achieve O(1) time complexity per query. However, I think there should be a way to handle it all better by somehow taking advantage of knowing all queries in advance, so maybe sorting those queries with their starting index and then doing some processing that way ?

Comment: @user1780424 I didn't understand from your question that you know all the queries in advance. How many are there relative to the size of the data?

Comment: let's say there are lots of queries. I can't tell exactly how much more relative to size of data, because they would be different units (one is query range sum, and another is just the 0001111s), but let's say 10x more.

Comment: @user1780424 as I understand, your data is never modified, the only considerable improvement that you can do is to not store a new array but modify the existing one, this way you answer each query with O(1) complexity, what could be better than that?

Answer (score 1):

I already gave an O(1) time, O(n) space answer. Here are some alternates that trade time for space.

**1. Assuming that the number of 1s is O(log n) or better (say O(log n) for argument):**

Store an array of ints representing the positions of the ones in the original array. so if the input is [1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1] then A = [0,4,6,7].

Given a query, use binary search on A for the start and end of the query in O(log(|A|)) = O(log(log(n)). If the element you're looking for isn't in A, find the smallest bigger index and the largest smaller index. E.g., for query (2,6) you'd return the indices for the 4 and the 6, which are (1,2). Then the answer is one more than the difference.

**2. Take advantage of knowing all the queries up front (as mentioned by the OP in a comment to my other answer). Say Q = (Q1, Q2, ..., Qm) is the set of queries.**

Process the queries, storing a map of start and end indices to the query. E.g., if Q1 = (12,92) then our map would include {92 => Q1, 12 => Q1}. This take O(m) time and O(m) space. Take note of the smallest start index and the largest end index.

Process the input data, starting with the smallest start index. Keep track of the running sum. For each index, check your map of queries. If the index is in the map, associate the current running sum with the appropriate query.

At the end, each query will have two sums associated with it. Add one to the difference to get the answer.

Worst case analysis:
O(n) + O(m) time, O(m) space. However, this is across all queries. The amortized time cost per query is O(n/m). This is the same as my constant time solution (which required O(n) preprocessing).

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go with something like this:

```
# boilerplate testdata
from itertools import chain, permutations
data = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1]

chained = list(chain(*permutations(data,5))) # increase 5 to 10 if you dare
```

Preprozessing:

```
frSet = frozenset([i for i in range(len(chained)) if chained[i]==1])
```

"Counting":

```
# O(min(len(frSet), len(frozenset(range(200,500))))
summa = frSet.intersection(frozenset(range(200,500))) # use two sets for faster intersect
counted=len(summa)
```

"Sanity-Check"

```
print(sum([1 for x in frSet if x >= 200 and x<500]))
print(summa)
print(len(summa))
```

No edge cases needed, intersection will do all you need, slightly higher memory as you store each index not ranges of ones. Performance depends on intersection-Implementation.

This might be helpfull: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set

Comment: Thanks for the approach Patrick. Very interesting method. However, assuming that frSet has much shorter length than length of the range query (because we have very few 1's), then the complexity will be O(|frSet|), where I think my approach would give me approximately O(log |frSet|) ?

Comment: @user1780424 Your log(n)stems from the binary search. 2 * log(n) is still log(n) - Go big O. Then you need some additionally logic to care for indexes that start somewhere inside and not exactly on the numbers stored in your arrays. So some additional constant factors - still log(n). On paper (and probably in real as well) you are faster- this one is easier to grasp though. Spacewise your data_sumsum could be shrunk by almost a half if you introduce an %2 on the idx gathered from data_change (you always record two of each on the 1 to 0 flanks). I am curios what other methods pop up